# How to check if Listview is empty

Tags: android, android-listview, parse-platform

My activity queries my parse database and then reuturns data as queried. The data is stored in terms of names in the listview. But I cant figure out how to check if the listview is empty. I want it to post an alert saying the list view is empty under the event it is. This is my activity

```
public class OfferPage extends Activity {
    String obj;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_offer_page);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        obj = i.getStringExtra("RestName");
        populateList(obj, "Restraunt");

    }

    private void populateList(final String Value, final String Key) {
        ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject> factory = new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {

            @Override
            @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
            public ParseQuery create() {
                ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Offers");
                query.whereEqualTo(Key, Value);
                return query;
            }
        };
        ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(
                this, factory);
        adapter.setTextKey("Offer");
        adapter.addOnQueryLoadListener(new OnQueryLoadListener<ParseObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onLoading() {
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(OfferPage.this);
                mProgressDialog.setTitle("Searching for Offers");
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoaded(List<ParseObject> objects, Exception e) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.offerList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

My main issue I cant seem to figure out where to put the check if the list is empty. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

You have to control if adapter is null,not the list view, cause adapter holds the values.

```
      if (adapter== null) {
            adapter= new  ParseQueryAdapter(this,getElements());
            eList.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            adapter.addAll(getElements());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using your adapter, you have to do youradapter.getCount(), that should give you the number of the elements in the listview, because when you populate the listview what you are really doing is entering the data from the adapter and creating the list items of that data.

Answer (score 0):

> The data is stored in terms of names in the listview.

Well, not really. ListView displays your data. Data itself is rather stored elsewhere. Binding listview with data is done with `Adapter` so to see if there's any data you just need to query Adapter by calling [getCount()](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQueryAdapter.html#getCount%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Use the method setEmptyView which sets the view to show if the adapter is empty.